# Problem about a series which defines a continuous function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to solve this problem:

> Show that the series $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin (x n)}{n^\alpha}$
> defines continuous function on $\Bbb R$ for $\alpha>1$."

First of all what I can say is that this series converges since it is smaller than $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$, so by weierstrass also the first series converges. I don't know how to procede. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome. What did you try? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hi Stéphane I tried to solve the problem. 
First of all what I can say is that this series converges since it is smaller than 1/n^alpha, so by weierstrass also the first series converges.
I don't know how to procede. Have you got any suggestions?

Comment: As @MartinR wrote to you, you can write your work directly in your post (with "edit") rather than in the comments only: this will allow everyone to see it and help you :).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
\begin{equation*}
\left|\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}\right| \leq \sum_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{n^\alpha}
\end{equation*}

You essentially want to show the sequence of partial sums is uniformly convergent

Answer (score 0):

As you have pointed out, you have a uniform limit by Weierstrass M-test, since $\alpha>1$.

Then, you have the theorem  that the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous maps is continuous to conclude, since $$\forall n \in \Bbb N^*, x\mapsto f_n(x)=\frac{sin(nx)}{n^\alpha}$$is continuous.